# Python exponent returns 1

Tags: python

I have written this simple code in python and I can not figure out why the answer returned is incorrect. This is the code:

```
x = float(raw_input("Input:"))
print(x)
x = x ** ( 1/3 )
print(x)
```

Running this same code in Python Shell (python.org/shell) returns the correct answer.

[image: On shell]

However, running the code on my linux machine always returns 1, no matter the input.

[image: In Linux]

I initially thought the problem was with `raw_input`, but after removing it from the code, nothing changed.

```
x = float(17.2)
print(x)
x = x **( 1/3 )
print(x)
```

How can I fix the code so that it returns the proper answer?

Comment: For division import the division module `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2,   1/3  is integer floor division and returns zero.
Anything raised to the power of zero is one.
Python3 would give you the result you expect.